# Emulator Error NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem when I start my app on the emulator. When I launch the app on my device, it works properly. Instead, when the emulator startup does not work. The error that comes to me is this:

```
04-05 15:31:54.570 22596-22596/com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale, PID: 22596
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale/com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
       at com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
       at com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
       at com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189)
       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:258)
       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:173)
       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
       at com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189) 
       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:258) 
       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:173) 
       at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
       at com.application.marcocicala.campaniacentrocommerciale.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.L
```

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You have the design support library added to your build.gradle file?

Comment: yes! compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

Comment: And the design support library is the same version as the appcompat support libraries? Ex: appcompat-v7:23.2.1

Comment: this is my dependencies

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
}

Comment: the error message only comes out when I start with the emulator API 23. But on my smartphone I have this problem.

Comment: It's probably something with your nav_header_main or activity_main_drawer files. Check this answer to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31289186/1478764. Also, I'm not sure why you are using NavigationView this way, normally one would put it as the second child in a DrawerLayout.

Comment: I try to write code in a new project. It is a strange error, write the result here if I find the problem. Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: I solved! the problem was when to change the background in the xml file "nav_header_main.xml". I changed the image and the problem has disappeared. I do not know why, but the problem was only in the emulator, maybe the picture was of large dimensions.